# Arduino LCD Display drawing image issue

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd

I am playing with 3,5" (400x240) TFT display which is placed into Arduino Mega 2560 R3 board.

My final *goal* is taking .raw data from SD card and drawing it on display.

What I have done so far:

**-** My **drawing** method in the sketch:

```
void LoadImage(File& file)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < SCREEN_HEIGHT && file.available(); y++) {
        uint16_t buf[SCREEN_WIDTH];
        for (int x = SCREEN_WIDTH - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            byte l = file.read();
            byte h = file.read();
            buf[x] = ((uint16_t)h << 8) | l;
        }
        myGLCD.drawPixelLine(0, y, SCREEN_WIDTH, buf);
    }
}
```

**-** For reference **drawPixelLine** method's implementation from UTFT library:

```
void UTFT::drawPixelLine(int x, int y, int sx, uint16_t* data)
{
    unsigned int col;
    cbi(P_CS, B_CS);
    setXY(x, y, x+sx-1, y);
    for (int tc=0; tc<sx; tc++)
    {
        char* p = (char*)&data[tc];
        LCD_Write_DATA(*(p + 1), *p);
    }
    sbi(P_CS, B_CS);
}
void UTFT::setXY(word x1, word y1, word x2, word y2)
{
    if (orient==LANDSCAPE)
    {
        swap(word, x1, y1);
        swap(word, x2, y2)
        y1=disp_y_size-y1;
        y2=disp_y_size-y2;
        swap(word, y1, y2)
    }
        LCD_Write_COM(0x2a);
        LCD_Write_DATA(x1>>8);
        LCD_Write_DATA(x1);
        LCD_Write_DATA(x2>>8);
        LCD_Write_DATA(x2);
        LCD_Write_COM(0x2b);
        LCD_Write_DATA(y1>>8);
        LCD_Write_DATA(y1);
        LCD_Write_DATA(y2>>8);
        LCD_Write_DATA(y2);
        LCD_Write_COM(0x2c);                             
}
```

*My current rendering:*

[image: current result]

*Desired image:*

[image]

*TFT Lcd and Mega Board*
[image]

**UPDATE1**

I ran henningan test from utft library, drawing sin/cos graph and simple squares

[image]

Here is attempt to render yellow square 100x100 raw data

[image]

Comment: Have you tried drawing a solid image first?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I tried to render yellow square, but without success. Please, see my updated post

Answer (score 1):

I'have the same LCD from mcufriend and it doesn't work with original UTFT library.

Try modified version from https://github.com/dgolda/UTFT and use:

```
myGLCD(NIC35WS,38,39,40,41); //3.5" TFTLCD for arduino 2560 from mcufriend.com
```